# fill na values with groupby in PySpark

Tags: python, pyspark

How can I fill na values in a df car price column, using group by version and filling these na values using the median?

I did it this way using pandas:

```
median_price=df.groupby("version")["price"].transform("median")

df["price"].fillna(median_price, inplace=True)
```

But I can't think of this logic for pyspark... Could you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Hi there are two ways to get this done

1. Use the predefined functions

   from pyspark.ml.feature import Imputer
   from pyspark.ml.feature import Imputer

   imputer = Imputer(
   inputCols=['cars'],
   outputCols=["{}_imputed".format(c) for c in ['cars']]
   ).setStrategy("median")

   ## Add imputation cols to df

   df = imputer.fit(df).transform(df)

Now the df will have another column cars_imputed

2. The second method basically need you get the median of the column and then use

   from pyspark.sql import functions as F

median_value=df.select(F.median(F.col('cars')))
df= df.fillna(median_value,subset=['cars']

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent solution in pyspark is to partition by `version` and then calculate the `median` price over the partition. Finally use `coalesce` to fill the null values.

```
W = Window.partitionBy('version')
df1 = df.withColumn('price', F.coalesce('price', F.median('price').over(W)))
```

Example,

```
df.show()
+-------+-----+
|version|price|
+-------+-----+
|      a|  1.5|
|      a|  2.0|
|      a| null|
|      b|  7.0|
|      b|  9.0|
|      c|  1.0|
+-------+-----+


df1.show()
+-------+-----+
|version|price|
+-------+-----+
|      a|  1.5|
|      a|  2.0|
|      a| 1.75|
|      b|  7.0|
|      b|  9.0|
|      c|  1.0|
+-------+-----+
```